# Undefined local variable or method 'rolify'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cancan, rolify

In my Rails project, I am trying to set up user authentication and user roles using the following Gems:

- Devise
- Cancan
- Rolify

I had Devise up and working perfectly, but then when I went to set up CanCan and Rolify, I get this error in the **browser**:

```
NameError in Home#index

Showing C:/Sites/JustManage/app/views/devise/menu/_registration_items.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined local variable or method `rolify' for #<Class:0x3f48660>
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <% if user_signed_in? %>
2: 
3:   <li>
4:      <%= link_to('Edit registration', edit_user_registration_path) %>
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

Rails.root: C:/Sites/JustManage
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :subdomain, :first_name, :last_name

  # Make sure certain attributes are unique
  validates_uniqueness_of :email, :case_sensitive => false
end
```

**role.rb**

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :users_roles
  belongs_to :resource, :polymorphic => true

  scopify
end
```

**rolify.rb**

```
Rolify.configure do |config|
  config.use_dynamic_shortcuts
end
```

Let me know if you need me to post contents from any of my other files!

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. Restarting my server fixed it!

'When in doubt, ctrl-c out!'

Answer (score 1):

Is it safe to assume that you installed and subsequently required the rolify gem properly?...

Please verify that rolify is listed when you run `gem list` and that you have added `require 'rolify'` at the top of your user.rb file.

Comment: I added the `rolify` gem to my `gemfile`, then I generated a role using `rails generate rolify:role`.

Comment: When I added `require 'rolify` to the top of my `user.rb` file, I got this error: `cannot load such file -- rolify`

Comment: You need to run `bundle install` after you add the rolify gem to your Gemfile.

Comment: I ran `bundle install` but unfortunately I'm still getting that same `cannot load such file...` error. I mean I have all of the Rolify files in my application, and I did a `rake db:migrate` so all of the Rolify database tables should be there...

Comment: Are you using ActiveRecord STI? https://github.com/EppO/rolify/wiki/FAQ#when-i-start-rails-using-server-console-whatever-i-get-this-error

If not, please tell me which ruby/rails/rolify versions you're using.

Comment: I'm not really sure what ActiveRecord STI is. I know I'm not using Mongoid ORM however. I'm using Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.1, and Rolify 3.2.